Getting underlying datasource objects from a DashboardViewers DashboardItem
I am currently developing some dashboard functionality for a WinForms application. I was able to create a dashboard using the designer that meets my demands but now I am running into a problem, and I can’t seem to find any information clarifying if the DevExpress dashboard even supports what I am trying to do or not.
The dashboard consists of a handful of DashboardItems. Some have their drilldown functionality enabled and some don’t.
I would now like to retrieve the actual underlying datasource objects every time a user clicks a dashboard item and then display those objects in a separate grid.
Is there a way to do that? I would be grateful for any pointers in the right direction... the documentation doesn’t help me in this case anymore. If there is information missing just let me know!
Thank you very much.
